# ng-model value not updating in controller: Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I used this technique in another place and it worked but in this case it is not working. Here lane_title shows undefined. Am I missing something here.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="lane_title" placeholder="Title of the lane" >
<button ng-click="testScope()">Create</button>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.testScope = function(){
    alert($scope.lane_title);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: show more code?

Comment: If it is undefined it means its not available in the scope. Check if your scope is lost in the page. You can dump $scope and check if your variable is present. If not try to use $rootScope which is the parent of these scopes

Comment: Make sure that you are in the controller scope

Comment: you should initialize your lane_title or declare a default value on it. because angular model are always undefined if it is still untouched

Comment: Had you define the controller before use? Its loosing scope man, get it back!

Comment: when I used ng-controller="LoginCtrl" into the parent of these elements then it works. But when I use it in body tag it is not working. why??

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine. But make sure to initialize the model variable. Otherwise, it will print as `undefined`

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.lane_title = "";
$scope.testScope = function(){
    alert($scope.lane_title);
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <input type="text" ng-model="lane_title" placeholder="Title of the lane" >
<button ng-click="testScope()">Create</button>
</div>
```

Comment: when I used ng-controller="LoginCtrl" into the parent of these elements then it works. But when I use it in body tag it is not working. why??